# com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am using typeSafe config to load the properties from application.properties present under src/main/resources into Scala code. While running the code from eclipse, the properties are getting loaded. But while running as a jar file,its throwing me an error.

```
    com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key
```

Comment: how did you try to get the properties file can you share your code ?

Comment: The jar file contains the property file?

Comment: can you post the full exception ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks Wang for giving me a clue. Yes, the jar file contains the property file. But it was not able to find the file, as the property file was present in resouces folder. I got to know when I unzip the jar file. In code had provided the below.

```
val config=ConfigFactory.load("application.properties")
```

When i changed it to-

```
val config=ConfigFactory.load("resources/application.properties")
```

i am getting the properties. THANKS ALL.