# ConfigFactory.load() not fetching values from application.conf located outside build jar

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive

Am passing dev/uat/prod to the main class (written in spark/scala) as a parameter and expecting to fetch username/password of corresponding environment from config file located outside the build jar. Business demanded config file outside jar for dynamic edit.
I receive runtime exception "com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'username'" 
Please clarify 
1) What am I missing?
2) Can't application.conf be outside the build always to fetch always? Should I maintain application.conf part of src/main/resources and build jar to fetch values (references from [com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44495429/com-typesafe-config-configexceptionmissing-no-configuration-setting-found-for))?
3) Is there any way I can maintain application.conf OUTSIDE the jar always to facilitate dynamic edit?

````
//LoadFromOracleToHive class
var environment: String = _
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit =
  {
  environment = args(0)
val appConfig = ConfigFactory.load(s"application.conf").getConfig("Samp").getConfig(s"${environment}")
      val user :String = appConfig.getString("username")
      val pwd :String = appConfig.getString("password")
  }
//application.conf
HeNAppConf {
  dev {
    username = "userid_dev"
    password = "pwd_dev"
  }
  uat {
    username = "userid_uat"
    password = "pwd_uat"
  }
  prod {
    username = "userid_prod"
    password = "pwd_prod"
  }
}
//my spark-submit
spark-submit --class LoadFromOracleToHive \
--master yarn \
--deploy-mode client \
--driver-memory 4g \
--executor-memory 8g \
--num-executors 15 \
--executor-cores 5 \
--conf spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max=512m  \
--queue csg \
--files /home/myuserfolder/application.conf
--jars /home/myuserfolder/ojdbc7.jar  /home/myuserfolder/myjar prod \
--conf spark.driver.extraClassPath=-Dconfig.file=/home/myuserfolder/application.conf \
--conf spark.executor.extraClassPath=-Dconfig.file=/home/myuserfolder/application.conf
//error snapshot in attachment
```[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXT3Z.png
````